# delete specific checkbox in php

Tags: php, checkbox

My problem is, due to an array of pre-selected checkboxes, the user can mark the checkbox of a value he wants to delete, but my circle only deletes the first one and ignores the POST I make to delete the specific one, here is the code:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['paymet']);$i++)
        {
            if(isset($_POST['payment'])) {
                $_SESSION['payment'][$i] = "";
                for($j = $i; $j<count($_SESSION['payment']); $j++)
                {
                    if(isset($_SESSION['payment'][$j+1])) {
                        $_SESSION['payment'][$j] = $_SESSION['payment'][$j+1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['payment']);$i++)
        {
            if($_SESSION['payment'][$i] == NULL) {
                unset($_SESSION['foliopago'][$i]); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mis-spelling `payment` in the first `for` probably isn't helping.

Comment: You check if $_POST['payment'] is defined, but never combine it woth a $i or $j neither check its value. Please provide a var_dump($_POST) or your html form. Better not mix up $_GET and $_POST parameters.

Comment: Thank you @clemens321 I added the $i to my checkbox and $_POST['payment']